# Is the phrase"horse of the rider" correct?

Tags: grammar

Which phrase is correct?

> A.horse of the rider
>
> B.rider's horse

Are both of the phrases correct or are they both wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> The horse **of the rider**

This sounds wrong, because we would generally use the genitive (possessive) *-'s* and in such a simple sentence it creates a strange impression. For that simple phrase, we would say:

> The **rider's** horse.

However, once integrated into an even slightly more complex sentence, it can become less unnatural. Still not usual, but less weird. I've heard commentary at equestrian events that is structured like so:

> Now, this is impressive horse, but we still don't know if she will mature into such a balanced performer as Horseyname, the horse **of team-mate John Smith**.

I suspect it's the complex nature of the 'owner' of the horse that makes it more acceptable, as constructing that with a genitive *-'s* is clunky and ends up with "horse" a long way away from the action.

Answer (score -1):

> horse of the rider

is both akward and unclear, if not absolutely wrong

> rider's horse

is unclear without context, but could work depending on the context. For example:

> The rider took control at the quarter-mile post. It was the rider's horse for the rest of the race.

It is more common to use a name rather than simply "rider". for example:

> Windrush had been John's horse ever since he was a foal.

One would not be likely to say "the horse of John"

Answer (score -1):

Usually for living things we use **'s** to show possession and for non livings we use **of**.In English grammar even animals are treated as non-livings.
 Therefore

> rider's horse sounds correct.

Comment: The 's form is very commonly used with non-living things. "The book's cover", "The boat's hull", "the building's windows", "the mountain's summit", "The ocean's waves", "the plane's altitude", "the governent's position" and many others. Most of these could also use an "of" form, but often that is not done  Contrawise, one can use "of" for a person: "The Mark of Zorro", "The Gospel of John" ""The Tomb of Hadrian" (but "Grant's Tomb" and "Hadrian's wall")  "The works of Mozart", "The Labors of Hercules".  The answer is simply incorrect.